# Beautiful soup failing to parse this HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

We're using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse many websites successfully, but a few are given us problems. An example is this page:

http://www.designsponge.com/2013/04/biz-ladies-how-to-use-networking-to-improve-your-search-engine-rankings.html

We're feeding the exact source to beautiful soup, but it returns a stunted HTML string, though no errors...

**Code:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(site_html)
print str(soup.html)
```

**Result:**

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--&lt;![endif]--> </html>
```

I'm trying to determine what's tripping it up, but nothing jumps out at me looking at the html source. Does anyone have some insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try different parsers, the page parses fine with the `html5lib` parser:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5')
>>> len(soup.find_all('li'))
97
```

Not all parsers can treat broken HTML the same.

Comment: Thanks for the tip- however, the html5 parser is listed as "very slow" so we probably won't be switching over to it.

Comment: @Yarin: Still, it is also the best choice for broken HTML. Try the `lxml.html` parser too.