# BeautifulSoup finding wrong tags Python (only in windows)

Tags: python, linux, windows, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup in python and I'm having some troubles now to make it run. I have done several scripts in both windows and linux and I could always use the same script in both without having any problems. But now I have an script in python which runs in linux but in windows it does another thing.
The problem is that when i run this line: `container = soup.find(class_="medium-10 medium-offset-1 columnstext-center")` in linux it returns me a div with a lot of `<a href= ...> </a>` but in Windows it only gives me 1. So when i do `for href in container.find_all("a")` it only loops once in windows while it loops for each  in the page in linux.
I tried to update both bs4 but I still have this problem, also I rebooted both computers to see what's wrong.
Hope someone knows how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: Do you have lxml installed on Linux perhaps?

Comment: See [Beautiful Soup findAll doen't find them all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16322862) for example.

Comment: And [Beautiful soup failing to parse this HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15773977)

Comment: `lxml` is the default parser *if installed*. For broken HTML, what parsers find can vary wildly.

Comment: yes Martijn it was that! Didn't know how the parsers work, thanks for the info. Add an answer so I can put it as answered!